# Можно ли как то кастомизировать timepicker?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Можно ли как то кастомизировать timepicker или стоит делать свой кастомный? (без использования библиотек)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Стоит или нет определяет рынок. А можно или нет определяете вы. Поскольку запретов нет

Comment: А если можно, то как?)

Comment: Откройте библтотеки и посмотрите что там и как. Благо JS открытый

Comment: По-моему только что со мной произошел показательный казус. А действительно, как это их пилят кастомно - подумал я и решил глянуть на кодпене, выбрал что-то более-менее с виду, рандомный год, февраль конечно же, и выбирая день долистал до 50..